# NSXMLParser can not get the content of elements correctly

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

i have the following XMLParser but when i try to run it, it doesn't work properly.

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"results"])
    {
        currentJob = [SearchResult alloc];
    }

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"jobTitle"])
    {
        currentJob.jobTitle = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"location"])
    {
        currentJob.shortAddress = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"companyName"])
    {
        currentJob.employer = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"results"])
    {
        [self.jobs addObject:currentJob];
        currentJob = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

AND here is my foundCharakter Method:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

The output doesn't start from the beginning, it starts from the middle of the String...
I just can not understand, why some results look nice where some others don't.

What am i doing wrong ? How can i parse an xml properly ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thx in advance

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but none of these answers have, unfortunately, helped. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463277/nsxmlparser-ignoring-text-between-certain-tags

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code and works now:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

     if(!elementContentString) 
     elementContentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string]; 
     else 
    [elementContentString appendString:string];
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was having similar problems to you, everything worked fine except when parsing strings containing an ampersand (&). The parsed result only contained the end of the string (everything after the ampersand). I tried lots of different fixes with no success, but your code solved my problem :D

Comment: Thank u. I was having problems when parsing french text. This solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there any problem in your code, it is working fine at my end. I am using the twitter api for getting xml and it is giving me proper output.

Comment: So what do you  think the problem is ? Well i can parse it very well :) why can't XML Parser ? I mean the xml looks fine... Please help!

Comment: Hi, I just found out that, only the names with special(german or french)characters are not parsed correctly. I have no problem with standard english characters. Have you got any idea, how i can fix this ?